# How to create certain number of turtles on the road shapefile and specific area?

Tags: gis, netlogo

I have imported the road shapefile and polygon shapefile and already intersected with patches. I want to create a certain number of turtles in a specific polygon and turtles allow moving only on the road shapefile. 
For example, In polygon A have turtles 20, polygon B have turtles 30 and I want to let the number of these to show up on its own polygon.

What I have done is I have intersected the road and the polygon by using (I mean 2 `foreach` for road and polygon)

```
foreach gis:feature-list-of x
  [ vector-feature ->
    ask patches gis:intersecting vector-feature
      [blah blah blah...]
  ]
```

Then, I created turtles using this code

```
to setup
  create-walkers Population
  ask walkers
  [
    set wlocation one-of patches with [pcolor = red]
    ;I have assigned the road shapefile to red color.
    move-to wlocation
end
```

With only patches is RED, it's work,
BUT when I tried to `set wlocation one-of patches with [pcolor = red and pcolor = ;another color which is the color of polygon]` 
Netlogo got an error that

> `move-to` expected input to be an agent but got nobody instead

How could I solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have a basic misunderstanding about `patches`. In NetLogo, a patch is an area of the world and is a single unit. What that means is that the `patch` can ONLY have one colour. Try running this code (as a new model)

```
to testme
  ask patches
  [ set pcolor random 256
  ]
end
```

You can see the patches, each with a randomly allocated colour. Now type `inspect one-of patches` in the command centre and an `inspect` window will open for a randomly selected patch. You will see that one of the listed variables is `pcolor`.

Short answer - a patch can only have one colour, so your request for patches with colour A and colour B is meaningless.